# Writing to the return value of a function in PHP

Tags: php

[The PHP Language Specification](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/10-expressions.md) says:

> A variable is an expression that can in principle be used as an lvalue

and

> The value of a function call is a modifiable lvalue only if the function returns a modifiable value byRef.

and the grammar from [zend_language_parser.y](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y)

```
expr:
   variable T_CONCAT_EQUAL expr

callable_variable:
        simple_variable
            { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_VAR, $1); }
    |   dereferencable '[' optional_expr ']'
            { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_DIM, $1, $3); }
    |   constant '[' optional_expr ']'
            { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_DIM, $1, $3); }
    |   dereferencable '{' expr '}'
            { $$ = zend_ast_create_ex(ZEND_AST_DIM, ZEND_DIM_ALTERNATIVE_SYNTAX, $1, $3); }
    |   dereferencable T_OBJECT_OPERATOR property_name argument_list
            { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_METHOD_CALL, $1, $3, $4); }
    |   function_call { $$ = $1; }
;

variable:
        callable_variable
            { $$ = $1; }
    |   static_member
            { $$ = $1; }
    |   dereferencable T_OBJECT_OPERATOR property_name
            { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_PROP, $1, $3); }
;
```

**So why can't I do this in PHP 7.3?**

```php
<?php
$a = 'HELLO';
function &foo() { 
    global $a;
    return $a;
}

foo() .= ' WORLD';
echo $a;
```

```
PHP Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context in ...
```

To follow on from this question, with reference to the grammar above:

**When is it ok to have a function call on the left hand side of a simple/compound assignment expression?**

Comment: just a note: globals are 9/10 not the right thing to do - use parameters instead :)

Comment: Because the function call itself is not a variable (and I'm pretty sure `function &foo()` won't make the function a reference - to my mind it doesn't even make sense but I could be completely wrong)? You could do `$b = foo() . ' WORLD';`

Comment: [I stand corrected](https://www.elated.com/php-references/) ... interesting

Comment: Although the function `foo()` returns a reference, it doesn't mean that it's a variable in itself.  What you are trying to do is append something to a function call - which doesn't make sense.

Comment: You yourself cite above: "The value of a function call is a modifiable lvalue". The _value_ of a function call, not the function call itself. You want to assign something to the value, but you try to assign to the call. That is a difference.

Comment: Please also see the grammar which permits a function_call on the LHS of the concat equal expr.

Comment: I'm leaning towards this just being a bug in the grammar definition, but I'd be interested to hear from anyone with insight into why it would have been written that way. Note that you can simplify to use a straight-forward assignment `foo() = 42;` matches the `variable '=' expr` rule, and gives the same error when you try to run it.

Answer (score 2):

While you can return reference from function you can't write into that reference directly.

You have to assign the reference first.

```
$a = 'HELLO';
function &foo() { 
    global $a;
    return $a;
}

$b =& foo();
$b .= ' WORLD';
echo $a;
```

Comment: Oddly - that's exactly the conclusion I just got on my local machine... literally the only difference between your code and mine is that I've used double-quotes rather than single :D

Comment: Then why does the grammar permit a function_call on the left hand side of a T_CONCAT_EQUAL expression?

Comment: @bmewburn I have no idea why it's this way in zend's grammar, but the PHP docs explicitly states `To use the returned reference, you must use reference assignment`. [Link to documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php)

Comment: Actually, that might be a reason why it's fatal error and not a parse error.

Comment: The `function_call` might be part of `variable` because of this part of `expr` definition: `variable '=' '&' variable { $$ = zend_ast_create(ZEND_AST_ASSIGN_REF, $1, $4); }` and some similar definitions. But that's just a speculation.